# Style sparklines in R using dataui package

Tags: r, sparklines

I am using the dataui package to create sparklines. I want the colour of the diagonal fill to match the color of the sparkline.

So Company A will have a green line with green diagonal fill underneath and company B will have a red line with red diagonal fill underneath.

I can't seem to get the diagonal fill to take on more than one value.

[image]

Is this possible?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("dataui")
library("reactable")

df <- tibble(
  Company = c("A", "B"),
  Line = list(list(c(1, 2, 1)), list(c(2, 2, 1)))
)

colpal <- c("#00DA07", "#BB0337")

rt1 <- reactable(df,
        compact = TRUE,
        fullWidth = FALSE,
                 
        columns = list(
          Line = colDef(
            cell = function(value, index) {
              dui_sparkline(
                data = value[[1]], 
                height = 80,
                components = list(
                  dui_sparklineseries(
                    curve = "linear",
                    showArea = TRUE,
                    fill = "url(#area_pattern2)",
                    stroke = colpal[index]),
                  
                  # Diagonal fill lines
                  dui_sparkpatternlines(
                    id = "area_pattern2",
                    height = 4,
                    width = 4,
                    stroke =  colpal[index],
                    strokeWidth = 1,
                    orientation = "diagonal"
                  )
                  
                )
              )
            }
          )
        )
)
rt1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library("tidyverse")
library("dataui")
library("reactable")

df <- tibble(
  Company = c("A", "B"),
  Line = list(list(c(1, 2, 1)), list(c(2, 2, 1)))
)

colpal_fill <- c("url(#area_pattern2)",  "url(#area_pattern3)")
colpal_stroke <- c("#91a7ff", "#F1a0ff")
  
rt1 <- reactable(df,
        compact = TRUE,
        fullWidth = FALSE,
                 
        columns = list(
          Line = colDef(
            cell = function(value, index) {
              dui_sparkline(
                data = value[[1]], 
                height = 80,
                margin = list(top = 20, right = 20, bottom = 20, left = 20),
                
                components = list(
                  dui_sparkpatternlines(
                    id = "area_pattern2",
                    height = 4,
                    width = 4,
                    stroke = "#91a7ff",
                    strokeWidth = 1,
                    orientation = "diagonal"
                  ),
                  
                  dui_sparkpatternlines(
                    id = "area_pattern3",
                    height = 4,
                    width = 4,
                    stroke = "#F1a0ff",
                    strokeWidth = 1,
                    orientation = "diagonal"
                  ),
                  
                  dui_sparklineseries(
                    curve = "linear",
                    showArea = TRUE,
                    fill = colpal_fill[index],
                    stroke = colpal_stroke[index]
                  )
                )
              )
            }
          )
        )
)
rt1
```